# How manage all other http error not managed before?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I manage with success some http error code via htaccess redirecting to give page. For example:

```
Error 404 -> error404.html
Error 500 -> error500.html
```

But in general is possible manage all other error (not managed before) redirecting it in a unique page? For example:

For all error which not are 404 and 500 then redirect to:

```
Error XXX -> general-error.html
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you working with some kind framework?

Comment: Yes but as owner framework if mean this. In general no framework of third parts.

Comment: Do you mean that you are working with your own framework?

Comment: Yes and client wanted this feature. Of course nothng of so hard as the big framework,

Comment: Just to be sure.. whats wrong about try..catch?

Comment: Nothing of bad but i think which not is a clean solution catch all error-code and make a very long list which redirect to a same page :D For this i wanted to find a more elegant solution for it.

Comment: Why long list? `catch(Exception $e)` will catch error from every type, anyway, error handling is IMHO a complex topic, you need to choose if and when you are throw exceptions and how you handle them. personally I like to throw the lease exceptions I can and use validations instead.

Comment: catch (Exception $e) in htaccess?

Comment: Nope.. in your PHP code..

Comment: Forgive me, but i asked about htaccess. With php not is a problem it. The question is: can i do it with htaccess or not?

Comment: I don't know and I don't think you should error handling with it